# Rotational invariance and intrinsic properties of the measure.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that we have $v\in\Bbb R^3$ and we have a smooth function $s=s(|v|)$ such that $|v|^4\in L^1(s(|v|)dv)$.

It is easy to show (by passing to polar coordinates) that
$$\int_{\Bbb R^3}(v_1^4-3v_1^2v_2^2)s(|v|)dv=0.$$

I'd like to know if there exists a method to prove the same result without resorting to direct computation, only using the rotational invariance of the measure $s$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Averaging polynomials over a sphere usually leads to consideration of spherical harmonics. I will write  $v=(x,y,z)$ to avoid indices. Although the function $f(x,y,z) = x^4-3x^2y^2$ is not harmonic, its symmetrized version 
$$h(x,y,z) = f(x,y,z) + f(y,x,z) $$
is. Since $h$ is harmonic and vanishes at the origin, its integral on every sphere centered at $(0,0,0)$ is zero. But this integral is twice the integral of $f$ over said sphere. Same applies to integrals against any rotationally symmetric density.